# Withdrawals from HSA

Tags: united-states, hsa

I understand that qualified withdrawals from HSA are tax free. If I am right in my understanding, then why are withdrawals deducted from the HSA contribution on form 8889 to determine the tax-deductible HSA contribution?

To be specific, Line 10 "Qualified HSA funding distributions" is to be subtracted from the HSA contribution to determine the HSA deduction from taxable income.

I made withdrawals but they are qualified. Why then should I deduct them from my HSA contribution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I made withdrawals but they are qualified. Why then should I deduct them from my HSA contribution?**

You shouldn't, it sounds like you're putting that number in the wrong part of the form.

Line 10 of Part I (Qualified HSA funding distributions) does not refer to distributions from your HSA used to cover qualified health expenses, but rather distributions from other accounts used to fund your HSA. The [Form 8889 instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i8889.pdf) state:

> **Line 10** Enter on line 10 any qualified HSA funding distribution made
>   during the year. This is a distribution from your traditional IRA or
>   Roth IRA to your HSA in a direct trustee-to-trustee transfer. This
>   qualified HSA funding distribution is not included in your income, is
>   not deductible, and reduces the amount that can be contributed to your
>   HSA by you and from other sources (including employer contributions).
>   This distribution cannot be made from an ongoing SEP IRA or SIMPLE
>   IRA. For this purpose, a SEP IRA or SIMPLE IRA is ongoing if an
>   employer contribution is made for the plan year ending with or within
>   your tax year in which the distribution would be made.

The distributions you are referring to are recorded in Part II (HSA Distributions). The Part 1 Line 10 name is a bit confusing on it's own, but it makes a little more sense in the context of the section of the form. Part I is "HSA Contributions and Deduction" so all about how the HSA was funded and what portion of those funds are deductible.